# how to plot a line chart in R?

Tags: r, linechart

I have data in a file, they look this way :

```
frame_delay
0.000030
0.000028
0.000028
0.000028
0.000028
0.000028
0.000027
0.000027
0.000027
0.000027
0.000028
0.000027
....
```

I wrote this `R` script

```
delays <- read.table("../../data/frame_delay.dat", header=T)
plot(delays)
```

And get the following chart.

[image]

I wonder how to tune my code to get something more readable like this (forget about lines) where y-axis represent above values and x-axis any sequence of number from 1 to whatever.

[image]

Thanks for any reply !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
delays <- read.table("../../data/frame_delay.dat", header=T)
plot(row(delays), delays[, 1], type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: Ok! that sounds better than mine. Now how to change circles to lines ? the line I asked to don't care abour are the dotted one

Comment: @FopaLéonConstantin `type = "l"`. Take a careful look at `?plot`.

Comment: Of course this is equivalent to what I had posted earlier, other than the use of `rows()` (which is a good move).

Answer (score 0):

Give it an artificial X-axis, such as this (naming your data frame `x`):

```
plot(cbind(1:length(x[[1]]), x), xlab='Index')
```

This does the same thing, perhaps a bit more efficiently:

```
plot(1:length(x[[1]]),x[[1]], xlab='Index')
```

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Both expressions do seem to print the correct chart (but with points rather than lines), given his example data.

Comment: Of course he may want `type = "l"` but the absence of an abscissa variable is his real problem.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I was confused about passing a vector vs a data frame or matrix. But I definitely think they want `type = "l"`. I'm going to delete some of these comments now...